# MAPISendMail losing spaces

Tags: c++, windows, mapi

My application is using MAPISendMail to send email. The email is formatted with spaces. eg:

```
Date Sent        12/4/2018
```

However, when the email pops up in Thunderbird (my default email application), the spaces have all gone. It looks like it is interpreting the message as HTML.

If I make Outlook my default email package, this doesn't happen. Is there anything I can do from the application side (C++, Windows, MAPI) that will convince Thunderbird to leave the message alone? The documentation seems a bit vague on what the message parameters mean.

Fundamentally, the function that does the sending looks like this (where to, subject and body are strings filled and passed in):

```
MapiRecipDesc   rec;
MapiMessage     msg;
bool            sent = false;
LHANDLE         session = 0;

memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(MapiMessage));
memset(&rec, 0, sizeof(MapiRecipDesc));

rec.ulRecipClass = MAPI_TO;
rec.lpszName = (LPSTR)to;

msg.lpszSubject = (LPSTR)subject;
msg.lpszNoteText = (LPSTR)body;
msg.nRecipCount = (to != 0) ? 1 : 0;
msg.lpRecips = &rec;

ULONG e = MAPISendMail(session, (ULONG_PTR)hWnd, &msg, MAPI_LOGON_UI|MAPI_DIALOG, 0);
```

Comment: What does your sending code look like?  What does the actual raw email data that Thunderbird is receiving look like?  Are you using POP3 or IMAP to receive the email? http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ And FYI, Outlook has its own share of problems when displaying plain-text emails. I have a service that sends formatted plain-text emails containing tabs and line breaks in them, and Outlook likes to ignore the formatting randomly, so they sometimes appear as a jumbled mess :-(

Comment: The email is being displayed in Thunderbird as a new message to send, so it isn't "receiving" anything.

Comment: you didn't make it clear in your question that the problem is on the *sending* side, not the *receiving* side. What's with all the type casts? If you have to type cast so much, you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: The two LPSTR casts are there because the function takes a const char *, while MapiMessage requires a non-const char *. This is a nasty hack, but is there for legacy reasons.
The ULONG_PTR cast is there because MAPISendMail requires the HWND of the owning window to be passed in as a ULONG_PTR. (We can blame Microsoft for that one)

Comment: you should be using `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`, respectively. But OK. Do you have Thunderbird set to plain text or HTML as its default format?

Comment: It really can't matter. There is no way for me to know what a client will have their email program set to. So there is either a way to control the outcome from MAPI, or there isn't. From the deafening silence I have to assume there isn't. It looks like I am going to have to live with this, or start looking at more sophisticated email generation methods.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: why not just use SMTP directly instead of MAPI? Then you have full control over the email generation and submission. Just at the cost of needing the user to supply your app with server and login info.

Comment: I've used SMTP in other applications, where it makes sense to send directly (usually some form of server). For a desktop application this makes little sense. The user would need to configure things like their SMTP server, account name and password and the like. It makes much more sense to use their email package.
However, MAPI is quite old and limited, but I was hoping it wan's TOO limited. The code I am working with is quite old, and I really don't want to spend a long time going through a complete overhaul.